# Make google searches and "Ok, google" open in broswer, not Google "App"

Tags: search, google-pixel, google-search, 8.1-oreo, ok-google

Is it possible to change my settings so that the results to me asking a question through "Ok, google" or typing on the search bar in my home screen, open in my default browser instead of the Google "App"?

I dislike how the Google App isn't actually an app in the sense that I can't open it through the recent applications shortcut, and the broswer-like window isn't actually saved in memory anywhere for me to go back to if I switch out after a search. Additionally it doesn't allow me to filter search results by date, etc. like a normal Google search does.

Comment: In the past one could it from *Settings>Accounts & privacy and click the Open web pages*- not sure if that option still works

Comment: @beeshyams This only works for links opened from the "Google Now" or "Google News", not  from the results shown when using OK Google, or the Google search bar on the android home screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open Google app. Then go to Settings > Accounts & privacy > Open web pages in the Google app.

Turn the above toggle off and you can open the web pages from search result in your choice of browser. You are forced to install Chrome before but once that's done, any browser will handle the webpage to display the results.

**For results:**

I'm not sure of an alternative to the Ok Google. But for the widget or search bar at the homescreen, it is better to use the search widget from Chrome or Firefox instead of relying on the Google app widget. In that case, your search (not just webpages) will entirely open in your browser.

Comment: This only works for links opened from the "Google Now" or "Google News", not  from the results shown when using OK Google, or the Google search bar on the android home screen.

Comment: As i suggested in my answer, you can use the search bar from chrome instead of using the stock search bar on your homescreen. I don't have a solution for Ok Google.